# How to Observable.interval multiple http requests (forkjoin) in rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I wanted to create an HTTP polling mechanism, with these rules:

1. Call multiple http requests parallel (forkJoin)
2. Run those requests with interval (Polling)
3. Send data to subscribers only if it has new data (Distinct)

I only succeeded with the forkJoin (#1).
Still need some help with #2 & #3

I created a plunker for this,
https://embed.plnkr.co/iIe6pi1hwXjwvF1wIN42/

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be a matter of composing your forkJoin on top of the interval...

```js
// interval every 10 seconds
Observable.interval(1000)
  // we probably only need one set of AJAX calls running at a time,
  // so use switchMap here.
  .switchMap(() =>
    // wait for both of these to complete before emitting
    Observable.forkJoin(
      // get posts
      this.searchService.getPosts()
        // if that GET fails handle it somehow (returning an observable)
        .catch(handlePostsErrors),
      // get comment in parallel to posts
      this.searchService.getPostComment(1)
        // if that GET fails, handle it like above
        .catch(handlePostCommentErrors)
    )
  )
  // posts and comment will come through in an array because of forkJoin
  .subscribe(([posts, comment]) => doSomething(posts, comment))
```